# Asymptotic property of Bessel function

Tags: complex-analysis, functions, bessel-functions

I am wondering, are these properties of modified Bessel functions correct?

$\frac{I_{1}(z)}{I_{o}(z)}\approx 1$

and

$\frac{I_{0}(2z)}{I_{o}^{2}(z)}\approx z^{1/2}\pi^{1/2},$

for large $z.$ If so, does somebody have an idea how to show that, or recommend me some good literature? I used expansions, but didn't get me where I wanted.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Asymptotic_forms

Comment: Sorry, I did mistake. There shoulf be of course z. I am gonna edit it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the asymptotic expansion given in Winther's link, i.e.

$$I_a(z) = \frac{e^z}{\sqrt{2\pi z}}\left(1 - \frac{4a^2-1}{8z}+ O(z^{-2})\right) $$

You get 
$$I_0(z) = \frac{e^z}{\sqrt{2\pi z}}\left(1 + \frac{1}{8z}+ O(z^{-2})\right) $$
$$I_1(z) = \frac{e^{z}}{\sqrt{2\pi z}}\left(1 - \frac{3}{8z}+ O(z^{-2})\right) $$
$$I_0(z)^2 = \frac{e^{2z}}{4\pi z}\left(1 + \frac{1}{8z}+ O(z^{-2})\right)^2 $$
$$I_0(2z) = \frac{e^{2z}}{\sqrt{4\pi z}}\left(1 + \frac{1}{16z}+ O(z^{-2})\right)$$ and therefore
$$\frac{I_0(z)}{I_1(z)}= 1 + \frac{1}{2z} + O(z^{-2})$$
$$\frac{I_0(2z)}{I_0(z)^2}= \sqrt{\pi z} - \frac{3}{16}\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{z}} + O(z^{-3/2})$$
So your approximations are the correct first order asymptotic terms.

---

**Edit:** Here is a short derivation: Writing $x=1/z$ and omitting the exponential prefactors you get for large $z$, i.e. small $x$ using the geometric series
$$\frac{1}{1-a} = 1 + a + a^2 +  \cdots$$
$$\frac{I_0(z)}{I_1(z)} \approx \frac{1+\frac{x}{8}}{1-\frac{3x}{8}} \approx (1+\frac{x}{8})(1+\frac{3x}{8}) \approx 1 + \frac{x}{2}$$
$$\frac{I_0(2z)}{I_0(z)^2} \approx \frac{1+\frac{x}{16}}{(1+\frac{x}{8})^2} = \frac{1+\frac{x}{16}}{1+\frac{x}{4}+\frac{x^2}{64}}
\approx (1+\frac{x}{16})(1-\frac{x}{4}) \ \approx 1 - \frac{3x}{16}$$

I have calculated the inverse of your first quotient, so 
$$\frac{I_1(z)}{I_0(z)}= 1 - \frac{1}{2z} + O(z^{-2})$$

Comment: Thank you a lot. You really helped me.

Comment: Sorry, but when I looked at it more closely, how did you get the coefficent (what kind of operation did you use?) near $1/z$ and so on... I mean, how did you ged rid of fraction? I ve tried that using long polynomial division, but I ve got different results.

Comment: Sorry there was a wrong sign in the second quotient, see the edit.